# How to avoid to remove the root element of a XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to grey out the remove option of the root or parent element of a xsd file. It's working in its derived nodes but not in the root one.

This is working:

```
<xs:attribute name="user-login" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
```

This is not working in the parent element:

```
<xs:element name="MyProgram-Deploy" use="required">
```

[image: XML GUI showing black, not grey, Remove command]

Comment: What does *I'm trying to grey out* mean?

Comment: I have added a image. It means to disable this option

Comment: Are you asking a question particular to a specific XML editor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, what I did was to create a Java class inheriting from XMLNodeActionManager which is called from a inherit class of IMenuListener class.
This IMenuListener is called every time that you show up the context up, so you have to override the method createContextMenu() of a inherit class of XMLTableTreeViewer to use the previous listener.
In the XMLNodeActionManager class, I go over all options of the context menu and I remove the one that I don't want:

**XMLTableTreeViewer.createContextMenu -> IMenuListener -> XmlNodeActionManager.contributeActions**

**MyTestIMenuListener:**

```
    class MyTestNodeActionMenuListener implements IMenuListener {
    @Override
    public void menuAboutToShow(org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuManager manager) {
        SilecsXmlNodeActionManager nodeActionManager = new MyTestXmlNodeActionManager(
                ((IDOMDocument) getInput()).getModel(), MyTestXMLTableTreeViewer.this);
        nodeActionManager.fillContextMenu(manager, getSelection());          
    }
}
```

**MyTestXMLTableTreeViewer extend XMLTableTreeViewer:**

```
@Override
protected void createContextMenu() {
    MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager("#PopUp"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    contextMenu.add(new Separator("additions")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    contextMenu.addMenuListener(new MyTestNodeActionMenuListener());
    Menu menu = contextMenu.createContextMenu(getControl());
    getControl().setMenu(menu);
}
```

**MyTestXmlNodeActionManager extend XmlNodeActionManager:**

```
@Override
public void contributeActions(IMenuManager menu, List selection) {
    super.contributeActions(menu, selection);

    Node node = (Node) selection.iterator().next();

    IContributionItem removeMenuItem = null;
    try {
        IContributionItem[] menuItems = menu.getItems();
        for (IContributionItem menuItem: menuItems) {
            if (menuItem instanceof ActionContributionItem) {
                if (((ActionContributionItem) menuItem).getAction() instanceof AbstractNodeActionManager.DeleteAction) {
                    removeMenuItem = menu.remove(menuItem);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSD, `use="required"` is inappropriate for `xs:element`.  Instead use `minOccurs="1"` to indicate that the element is required.  Note, however, that a root element is declared globally, and `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` do not apply to globally declared elements.  There must be ***exactly one root element*** in an XML document; it's non-optional and cannot be repeated.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.
Are there any other method to gray out this option since "minOccurs" doesn't work in the global root element ?

Comment: Realize that phrasing your question in terms of "graying out" a menu command frames the problem in terms of a particular XML editor, which you've yet to name.   You'll get the best help by asking in terms of XML and XSD in general instead.  In order to make a specific root element required by an XSD, the best you can do is to make sure it's the only global element in the XSD.  Whether that suffices to disable the remove command for any given XML editor is an implementation detail of that editor.